# Javascript: Show alert when @hotmail account is being used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have customers who seem to get emails sent straight into their junk mail when using a Hotmail account. I would like to add some Javascript which could detect when someone has typed in @hotmail into the input.

Is this at all possible? If so, how would I go about implementing something like this? I would prefer to use JQuery and as always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now.

Comment: You can get the text inside your javascript and check if that string contains @hotmail inside it.

Comment: look into the onChange event for your input

Comment: `alert($(element).val().indexOf('@hotmail') != -1)`

Comment: I don't think anybody will write the code for you but a good start would be to check the text element (or whatever the address gets inserted into) if it matches `@hotmail`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#theInput").change(function()
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.match(/@hotmail/g) != null)
    {
        alert("Your alert");
    }
});
```

That should do it

Comment: Max, this always produces the alert, regardless of content.

Comment: Sorry forgot that match returns null and not false. I fixed it ;)

Comment: This one works perfectly, thank you so much for you're help. I had a feeling I would need an .change function, just wasn't sure on how to check the input. This works well and only alerts once which is a bonus. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

to check if an input has a string being search, you can use `.indexOf()`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/Nm5h9/)

you can then check what is being type in the inputbox like this

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.indexOf('@hotmail') != -1) {
        alert('no good email.')
    }
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/p7LLY/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the only trouble with this would be that the alert comes up constantly after you type @hotmail which would be quite annoying for most people.

Comment: @CheckeredMichael, you don't need to use alert... you can show/hide some text, or some sort of... alert was just an example to give you idea..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test for that exact string, it's relatively straight forward

```
if (/@hotmail/.test($(".myinput").val()) {
    //do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var email = $("#email").val();
   if( email.indexOf('@hotmail') > -1)
   {
       alert("contain @hotmail");
   }else
   {
       alert("no @hotmail");
   }
});
```

Working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fTp7m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$("#myTextBox").bind(" paste keyup", function() {
        var email=[];
         email=  $(this).val().split('@');
        if(email[1]==="hotmail.com")
      alert("HOTMAIL");
    });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/f58y5/